# Almacenar dato de la vista en el controlador

Tags: javascript, c#

resulta que rescato un dato del pc (gpu) y lo muestro en la vista, ese dato en especifico necesito mandarlo al controlador, ya que lo debo almacenar, intente hacerlo con tempdata pero me devolvio null, hay alguna forma de hacerlo?, adjunto mi codigo:

Vista:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "prueba";
}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft Visual Studio .NET
7.1">
    <meta name="vs_targetSchema"
          content="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5">
    <script id=clientEventHandlersJS language=javascript>
<!--

        function Button1_onclick() {
            var locator = new ActiveXObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator");
            var service = locator.ConnectServer(".");
            var properties = service.ExecQuery("SELECT * fROM Win32_DisplayConfiguration");
            var e = new Enumerator(properties);
            document.write("<table border=1>");
            for (; !e.atEnd(); e.moveNext()) {
                var p = e.item();
                document.write("<tr>");
                document.write("DeviceName: ");
                document.write("Nombre vga: ") + (p.DeviceName (@{TempData["vga"] = ViewBag.vga}) );

               /* document.write("<td>" + p.HostingBoard + "</td>");
                document.write("<td>" + p.Manufacturer + "</td>");
                document.write("<td>" + p.PoweredOn + "</td>");
                document.write("<td>" + p.Product + "</td>");
                document.write("<td>" + p.SerialNumber + "</td>");
                document.write("<td>" + p.Version + "</td>");
                document.write("</tr>");*/
        }


            document.write("</table>");
        }

        //-->
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <INPUT id="Button1" type="button" value="Button"
           name="Button1" language=javascript onclick="return Button1_onclick()">
</body>
</html>
```

Controlador:

```
   public ActionResult prueba()
    {
        string y = (TempData["vga"]).ToString();
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segun entiendo desde el lado del cliente quieres establecer el valor de ViewBag?  acciones de Razor  siempre son del lado del servidor, del lado del cliente ViewBag no existe, revisa [sintaxis razor](https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/la-sintaxis-razor.html)
si quieres enviar informacion desde el cliente (usuario) a un controlador debes hacer un http post.

a continucion el pseudo codigo, solo para indicarte los pasos  que puedes seguir:
en tu pagina declaras

```
function enviaNombreDisplay(vgaNombre, UrlControlador) {
    $.ajax({
        url:  UrlControlador,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ 
           DisplayName:vgaNombre
        }),
        success: alert('dato enviado'),
        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
            alert('Error message.');
        }
    });
}
```

en tu pagina html

```
 ....
 document.write("DeviceName: ");
                document.write("Nombre vga: ") + (p.DeviceName)
  enviaNombreDisplay(p.DeviceName,"TuUrlControlador/Prueba")
...
```

en tu controlador

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Prueba(DisplayConfiguracion model)
{
  var y=model.DisplayName;
}
```

Nota1:  elaborar consultas desde el cliente para nada es recomendable.

```
 var properties = service.ExecQuery("SELECT * fROM Win32_DisplayConfiguration");
```

Comment: Muchas graciaas, te comento!, solo elaboro una consulta para ver ese dato y sumarlo a 3 datos mas, por ejemplo, que windows ocupa etc, todo eso lo convierto en un codigo hash y lo comparo con el que esta en el servidor, fue una manera que me propusieron en el trabajo para que no copien nuestro programa.

Comment: Se envio el dato, gracias Miguel!